# How to pass a std::function with capture through a C API?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

I have a C API that is a queue used to pass messages between threads. I want to pass a `std::function<void()>` through it, but to do that, I need to degrade it to a POD chunk of data of constant length.

The `std::function` will be mostly from C++11 lambdas and will capture by reference or copy. I can use the heap from both sides of the C-queue.

The queue itself is a FreeRTOS queue and this is in embedded. There is some [discussion about passing C++ish things through the queue](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/September_2011/freertos_C_Passing_varying_objects_from_task_to_task_4693307.html) on their forums. It mostly says it's ok if it's a POD or is trivially constructable.

Currently I'm passing around `struct { void (*fp)(void*); void* context; }`, and execute it as `received.fp(received.context)`; but I'd like something a bit better in terms of readability without sacrificing much more resources. (EDIT: expanded on current use and needs)

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What the `void*` parameter intended to be used for? It's probably better to provide a `static` class function and pass the containing class instance as `void*` and cast back in the implementation.

Comment: Traditional interface for C is something like `void register(void (*callback(void*), void* userData)`. so `userData` is your class, and `callback` casts `void*` into your class before calling expected method.

Comment: What counts as "better"? What constraints do you have on performance, allocation, etc. etc?

Comment: How much storage do you have in the queue to pass the message?  As much as you want?  What do you need to capture in the `std::function`, exactly?

Comment: user0042: the parameter is for passing context to it later on. Jarod42: this is pretty much the same as I'm currently using.

Comment: @Useless: better is mostly prettier (that is more readable) without adding much new overhead. I'm constrained mostly by stack size and main heap on my platform and have lots of a slow external heap with restricted usage that I can use with placement new.

Comment: @Yakk: many things, the queue in question is a worker that is used from many places - and will capture different depending on use (probably constrained to 50 bytes a call). Lots of things need to be run in sequence and instead of synchronizing them in their own threads, they're all run on one common one. This is done mostly so that they can share a larger stack that I could not afford to give them separately. About queue size, I have enough space there to store captured params, but heap is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about FreeRTOS, but with your requirements, you should be able to use a pointer to your `std::function` object (either heap-allocated or a pointer to a non-heap allocated object if its lifetime permits) -- all raw pointers are POD, even if they point to C++ objects.

Here's a quick example of using a pointer to a bound `std::function` allocated on the stack:

```
std::function<void()> produce(int value)
{
    return [value]() {
        std::cout << "Value = " << value << std::endl;
    };
}

void consume(std::function<void()> *callback)
{
    (*callback)();
}

int main()
{
    auto cb = produce(42);
    consume(&cb);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP needs a function of signature `void(void*)`.

Comment: OP doesn't need one, it was just a way to go through the C API.  As said in the first two paragraphs of the question, `std::function<void()>` containing a lambda with capture is what is needed.

Comment: Not sure why have I newer thought of something so simple, could not use exactly this, but it looks like `new std::function<void()>([&] { /*...*/ }` works just as well.

Comment: Accepting this answer, because it is simple, works in my case and while Soonts's answer was as valid as this one, you were a few minutes faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a pointer to your `std::function<void()>`. Pointers are POD. You can use casts to enqueue/dequeuer, and use heap i.e. new/delete to allocate/deallocate.

However, if that’s embedded and you have large rate of these messages (I’d say more than 100-1000 messages per second), it’s not necessary a good idea to stress memory manager this way. If that’s your case, I’d reworked the messages so they don’t use dynamic memory, allocated an adequately-sized pool for the in-flight messages (if you have 1 consumer and 1 producer, the adequate size is probably RTOS queue length + 2), and used something to recycle the message pointers back to the pool once your consumer thread[s] consumed a message.

Unfortunately this increases complexity a lot. No dynamic memory means no lambdas, and that recycling pool needs to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

I am first going to solve your problem exactly, then show you the way to solve it in a generic way that will work for many different C APIs.

```
struct c_api {
  void(*f)(void*);
  void* ptr;
};
template<class F>
c_api c_api_wrap( F* f ) {
  return {
    [](void* pv) { (*static_cast<F*>(pv))(); },
    f
  };
}
```

this takes a pointer to a `std::function` (or a lambda, I don't care), and creates a tuple of pointer-to-void and pointer-to-function.

Invoking pointer-to-function on pointer-to-void calls the `std::function` (or lambda).

---

This is the generic solution:

```
template<class Sig>
struct c_api;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct c_api<R(Args...)> {
  using fptr = R(*)(void*, Args...);
  fptr f = nullptr;
  void* ptr = nullptr;
  template<class F>
  explicit c_api( F* pf ):
    f([](void* vptr, Args...args)->R {
      return (*static_cast<F*>(vptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }),
    ptr(pf)
  {}
};
// not needed unless you want to pass in a non-void returning
// function to a void-returning C API:
template<class...Args>
struct c_api<void(Args...)> {
  using fptr = void(*)(void*, Args...);
  fptr f = nullptr;
  void* ptr = nullptr;
  template<class F>
  explicit c_api( F* pf ):
    f([](void* vptr, Args...args) {
      (*static_cast<F*>(vptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }),
    ptr(pf)
  {}
};

// wrap a pointer to an arbitrary function object to be consumed
// by a C API:
template<class Sig, class F>
c_api<Sig> c_wrap( F* f ) {
  return c_api<Sig>(f);
}
```

in your case, you want `c_wrap<void()>(&some_std_function)`.  From that, you can access `.ptr` and `.f` to pass to your C API.

It doesn't manage memory at all.

You can pass additional args or handle return values by changing the `void()` signature; however, it assumes the `void*` "self" component is the first argument.  A fancier version can support the `void*` anywhere, but that gets verbose.

In case you are wondering how this works, a stateless lambda can be converted to a functoin pointer, which is what we use in the `c_api` constructor above.

Comment: With a static member function instead of lambda you would not need the 2 specializations.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The 2 specializations are there in order to permit a non-void returning function to be passed in to a c api expecting a function returning void.  A static member function doesn't help there.  It is permitted in generic code to `return f(whatever)` in a `void` returning function where `f(whatever)` itself returns void, but not if `f(whatever)` does not return void.

Comment: This code isn't the easiest to understand :P Depending on the usage, I'd write `return R(f(whatever));` to avoid the specialization.